# Getting the data from more then one Controller & post item into the server using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

The thing that i am having more than one controller & through that controller we want to get the data & at last , want to post that data into the dbserver .,

below i have added the service & the contoller how i have used "That i am getting the last Pushed value only how can i modify the service " plz suggest me am new to angularJs so., am getting confused ,Thank you

```
 //Module
 var app = angular.module('application', []);


 //Service
app.service('InstanceService', function () {
var instancedetails = [];

var addinstance = function (newObj) {
    instancedetails.push(newObj);
};

var getInstances = function () {
    return instancedetails;
};

return {
    addinstance: addinstance,
    getInstances: getInstances
};

});

//controller1
app.controller('page2ctrl', function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {

$scope.Page2data = null;
$scope.message = "";

$scope.instancedata = {
    InstanceID: '',
    CompanyName: '',
    AccessName: '',
    FullName: '',
    EmailAddress: '',
    MobileNumber: ''
};



$scope.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.instancedata.CompanyName != "" && $scope.instancedata.AccessName != "") {

        InstanceService.addinstance($scope.instancedata);

        window.location = 'Page3'
  }

    else {
        alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
    }

}

});


//Controller2 
app.controller("bannerCtrl",function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {
$scope.bnnrdata = {
    Banner: ''
}
$scope.savebnnr = function () {
    InstanceService.addinstance($scope.bnnrdata);

    window.location = 'Ammineties';


}
});

//Controller3 
app.controller("AmminitesCtrl", function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {

$scope.ammdata = {
    Currency: '',
    Language: '',
    Timezone: ''
};
$scope.saveAmm = function () {
    InstanceService.addinstance($scope.ammdata);

    $scope.Inst = InstanceService.getInstances();

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Instance/postitem',
        data: $scope.Inst
    });
    window.location = 'Page5';


   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following will do your work. How ever I didnt test it as  I dont have your HTML and comment if you face any error. The lines which I modified are prefixed with a comment **//Line Modified as below**

```
var app = angular.module('application', []);


 //Service
app.service('InstanceService', function () {
var instancedetails = [];

var addinstance = function (newObj) {
    instancedetails.push(newObj);
};

var getInstances = function () {
    return instancedetails;
};

return {
    instancedetails:instancedetails,
    addinstance: addinstance,
    getInstances: getInstances
};

});

//controller1
app.controller('page2ctrl', function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {

$scope.Page2data = null;
$scope.message = "";

$scope.instancedata = {
    InstanceID: '',
    CompanyName: '',
    AccessName: '',
    FullName: '',
    EmailAddress: '',
    MobileNumber: ''
};



$scope.submit = function () {
    /*Directly assign it to that object*/
    //Line Modified as below
  InstanceService.addinstance.push($scope.instancedata);

    if ($scope.instancedata.CompanyName != "" && $scope.instancedata.AccessName != "") {
//If your checking some conditions add the line here 
   //     InstanceService.addinstance($scope.instancedata);
//Line Modified as below
        window.location = '/Page3'
  }

    else {
        alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
    }

}

});


//Controller2 
app.controller("bannerCtrl",function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {
$scope.bnnrdata = {
    Banner: ''
}
$scope.savebnnr = function () {
//Line Modified as below
    InstanceService.instancedetails.push($scope.bnnrdata);
//Line Modified as below
    window.location = '/Ammineties';


}
});

//Controller3 
app.controller("AmminitesCtrl", function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {
 //added
 $scope.Inst=[];
$scope.ammdata = {
    Currency: '',
    Language: '',
    Timezone: ''
};
$scope.saveAmm = function () {
    //Line Modified as below
    InstanceService.instancedetails.push($scope.ammdata);

    //Line Modified as below
    $scope.Inst = InstanceService.instancedetails;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Instance/postitem',
        data: $scope.Inst
    });
    //Line Modified as below
    window.location = '/Page5';
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That am used "window.location='/page5'" for redirecting to the next page through this the whole service & the all the objects will be recreated so for that reason am getting the values null & last pushed value will be present in that array.,

so i used instead of window.location ==> "$location.path('/Page5');"  through This am solved my error
Thanks for suggestion who r all guided.